# Existing tools to find unused tables in cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, open-source, datastax, distributed-system

We've bunch of prod and non-prod cassandra clusters on-prem. I was wondering to be able to run some open source tools which would give me insights about the tables in the clusters, basically how many are system and user keyspaces/tables and how many are unused i.e. no read/write activity in last 15 days or so etc. I'm thinking such tools would be available already since developeing them is easy. But I can't dig up tools like this from searching internet.
If someone can direct me to any tools they use for similar purposes, that'd help
We are using cassandra datastax 5.1.33 in our clusters

Tried google search
Tried nodetool tablestats and writting my own script to compile data and extract info but looking for an existing tool to save time and effort

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid [**DataStax Enterprise (DSE) `5.1` subscription**](https://www.datastax.com/legal/datastax-faq-direct-licensing), you could setup & configure [**OpsCenter `6.8`**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/docs/installing/opscenter-contents.html) that comes for free of license to use with **DSE**.

With OpsCenter `6.8`, one can [configure individual table level reads/writes to monitor for any traffic](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/online-help/metrics-reference.html) and then decide to drop them based on usage.

In addition to that, one could also leverage [**`nodetool tablestats`**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/docs/managing/tools/nodetool/table-statistics.html) and look out for the `Local read|write latency` (or) `Local read|write count` metrics to understand if the table in question is being used since the time the DSE process was restarted.

Comment: With OpsCenter 6.8, one can configure individual table level reads/writes to monitor for any traffic and then decide to drop them based on usage.

---Not feasible when cluster has > 20 tables. Can't have individual graphs plotted and monitored

The nodetool tablestats approach is what I'm doing right now and building my own software around it. Plan would be to execute it once a month kind of way and send out reports on unused tables for cleanup. Instead of writing the code myself from scratch, i was hoping to find existing tools that'd do this already. Seemed like a good idea to implement

Comment: Yes, you can turn on for an individual table even if your cluster has a total of > 20 tables. When adding a new graph, use the ones that start with `TBL` and you can zero in on a given single table. You probably have missed it.